# Why does PHP 7.3.2 show the wrong time and ignores timezone?

Tags: linux, debian, php

Since I updated to **PHP 7.3.2** a few hours ago (PHP 7.3.2-1+0~20190207180136.30+stretch~1.gbp501c1c), PHP always shows the wrong time when I call the "date" function. I set the timezone to "Europe/Berlin" and verified it by "phpinfo".

Even if I specify the timezone **in a script** using "date_default_timezone_set" and then call the "date" function, it shows 08:20 instead of 09:20 (**one hour difference**), so UTC instead of UTC +1...

I think, that must be a PHP 7.3.2 bug, because no matter what timezone I set, the time that php outputs is always the same (UTC). My system time on the server (Debian 9) is correct and I reproduced this problem on **different servers** just after I updated to PHP 7.3.2.

Does anyone else have this problem or is this already a known issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Official bug tracker](https://bugs.php.net/search.php?limit=30&order_by=id&direction=DESC&cmd=display&status=Open&bug_type=All&phpver=7.3)

There seem to be known problems that seem to depend on your distribution/repository/way you installed PHP in relation to using timezones.

Comment: Okay, thanks, then it has to be an issue on the PPA side (https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=77582) and I hope that it will be fixed soon

Comment: I'm having same trouble here. Even with correct timezone and setting at script's begin, it shows wrong time.

Comment: unfortunately it was not fixed - 7.3.27 has this problem .. still